# CSS not applied to Webpacked module

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack

I'm fairly new to building my own `webpack.config.js` and I'm trying to use the Noty module (to display modal notifications), installed via `npm`.

It seems that I manage to import the Noty javascript, but not the CSS: the notification appears at the very bottom of my page without any style whatsoever when it should be a red box at the top center.

My understanding of Webpack being quite shallow, I have no idea what the problem is! Below is my `webpack.config.js` and the file trying to use Noty.

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './front/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
              test: /\.html$/,
              loader: 'html-loader',
            },
        ]
    },
};
```

### music.js

```
import Noty from 'noty';
import request from './request';

export default class Music {
    loadSongVersion(songVersionId, audioElement) {
        request(`/api/song-version/${songVersionId}`)
            .then((songVersion) => {
                audioElement.src = songVersion.src;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`Could not fetch song version by ID ${songVersionId}`);
                new Noty({
                    text: 'Error while fetching this song version',
                    layout: 'topCenter',
                }).show();
            });
    }
};
```

If any of you has an idea of what the problem is, I'd be infinitely grateful!

Comment: you have two style loaders that are identical and you are also not loading any css located in the node_modules folder (I'm not sure if the latter is actually the issue but I'd hazard a guess to remove that exclude of node_modules on the css loader)

Answer (score 1):

You have two entries:

```
       {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        }
```

The first excludes all css files in node_modules and the second includes them.

Remove the *excludes* and it should work. But I would further recommend that you specifically only include the noty css files since including all css willy-nilly might include some cruft that you don't want.

So, the final entry should look something like this:

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: /node_modules/noty/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        }
```

Comment: Yeah it seemed weird to me too, it came from a boilerplate I used on another project.
It doesn't seem to work thought, neither with `/noty` nor without :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this to music.js:

```
import 'noty/lib/noty.css'
```

Ref: https://github.com/needim/noty/issues/368